# Complex SQL Query using AVG and count

Tags: sql, t-sql, average

I am looking for some help with two queries using the following table/data. It would be great to see the most efficient way to achieve these.

**Queries**

1: Show all homes with rent above the average rent value for their Company

2: Show the number of homes registered 0-3 months, 4-6 months, 6-12 months, 1- 2 years, and 2+ years ago

Thank you for looking.

```
CREATE SCHEMA homes;

GO

CREATE TABLE homes.Companies (CompanyId INT, CompanyName NVARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO homes.Companies VALUES
 (1,'Company A')
,(2,'Company B')
,(3,'Company C')
,(4,'Company D')

CREATE TABLE homes.Branches(BranchId INT, CompanyId INT, BranchName NVARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO homes.Branches VALUES
 (1,1,'Liverpool')
,(2,1,'Blackpool')
,(3,1,'Stockport')
,(4,2,'Durham')
,(5,2,'Oxford')
,(6,2,'Cambridge')
,(7,2,'Manchester')
,(8,3,'Newcastle')
,(9,3,'Hull')
,(10,3,'York')
,(11,4,'Birmingham')
,(12,4,'Stoke on Trent')


-- DROP TABLE homes.Properties;
CREATE TABLE homes.Properties (PropertyId INT, BranchId INT, Address NVARCHAR(200), Rent INT, RegisteredOn DATETIME);
INSERT INTO homes.Properties VALUES
 (1,1,'12a, Station Street, Liverpool',500,CAST('2019-12-31' AS DATETIME))
,(2,1,'12c, Station Street, Liverpool',475,CAST('2021-06-15' AS DATETIME))
,(3,3,'39, Main Road, Stockport',410,CAST('2022-09-30' AS DATETIME))
,(4,3,'12, Dovetrees, Manchester',700,CAST('2022-08-19' AS DATETIME))
,(5,5,'16, St Giles, Oxford',825,CAST('2023-02-28' AS DATETIME))
,(6,5,'32, George Street, Oxford',1100,CAST('2022-04-01' AS DATETIME))
,(7,5,'16, Main Road, Eynsham',680,CAST('2021-03-24' AS DATETIME))
,(8,6,'3b, University Road, Cambridge',960,CAST('2022-01-14' AS DATETIME))
,(9,7,'98, Heaton Road, Manchester',795,CAST('2022-09-07' AS DATETIME))
,(10,8,'64, St James Park, Newcastle',550,CAST('2022-11-26' AS DATETIME))
,(11,8,'47, St James Park, Newcastle',630,CAST('2023-01-16' AS DATETIME))
,(12,10,'6b, Station Lane, York',520,CAST('2022-07-19' AS DATETIME))
,(13,10,'24, Newcastle Road, York',510,CAST('2022-03-15' AS DATETIME))
,(14,11,'64, Bull Ring, Birmingham',1025,CAST('2022-12-03' AS DATETIME))
,(15,12,'Willowmead, Pottery Lane, Stoke on Trent',765,CAST('2022-05-12' AS DATETIME))
```

Comment: Homework, nice! But if we did it for you, you wouldn't learn much.

Comment: You have misunderstood what stackoverflow is for. You are supposed to come here with a concrete problem where you got stuck. So, think about how to approach the tasks, write the queries, and if you get stuck, show us your best effort and explain the issue with your query you are unable to solve.

Comment: Well I think for my question 1, something like.  ---  `code` select c.companyid,  c.companyname, p.PropertyId, p.Address, p.Rent FROM [homes].[Branches] b join [homes].[Properties] p on b.branchid = p.branchid join [homes].[Companies] c on b.CompanyId = c.CompanyId WHERE p.rent > (
        SELECT avg(rent) FROM [homes].[Properties] 
    ) `code`

Comment: That is close. In the subquery you'd have to join the tables again, though, in order to relate the company of the subquery to the main query.

Answer (score 1):

1. To show all homes with rent above the average rent value for their
   Company :

```sql
SELECT p.PropertyId, b.BranchName, p.Address, p.Rent
FROM homes.Properties p
JOIN homes.Branches b ON p.BranchId = b.BranchId
JOIN (
    SELECT c.CompanyId, AVG(p.Rent) AS AvgRent
    FROM homes.Properties p
    JOIN homes.Branches b ON p.BranchId = b.BranchId
    JOIN homes.Companies c ON b.CompanyId = c.CompanyId
    GROUP BY c.CompanyId
) AS subquery ON b.CompanyId = subquery.CompanyId
WHERE p.Rent > subquery.AvgRent;
```

The query above joins the `Properties` table with the `Branches` table and then joins with a subquery which calculates the average rent per company.
It selects only the properties where the rent is above the average rent for their company.

2. To show the number of homes registered 0-3 months, 4-6 months, 6-12
   months, 1-2 years, and 2+ years ago

```sql
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, p.RegisteredOn, GETDATE()) <= 3 THEN '0-3 months'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, p.RegisteredOn, GETDATE()) <= 6 THEN '4-6 months'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, p.RegisteredOn, GETDATE()) <= 12 THEN '6-12 months'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, p.RegisteredOn, GETDATE()) <= 2 THEN '1-2 years'
        ELSE '2+ years'
    END AS TimeRange,
    COUNT(*) AS HomeCount
FROM homes.Properties p
GROUP BY
    CASE
        WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, p.RegisteredOn, GETDATE()) <= 3 THEN '0-3 months'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, p.RegisteredOn, GETDATE()) <= 6 THEN '4-6 months'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, p.RegisteredOn, GETDATE()) <= 12 THEN '6-12 months'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, p.RegisteredOn, GETDATE()) <= 2 THEN '1-2 years'
        ELSE '2+ years'
    END;
```

The use of `DATEDIFF` function is to calculate the difference in months/years between the `RegisteredOn` date of each property and the current date `GETDATE()`. Then, it groups the properties based on the calculated time range and counts the number of properties in each range.

Comment: These are good solutions. The first query would benefit from a `WITH` clause (aka CTE) in my opinion. Or it could be written with a window function (`AVG OVER`) to get this query shorter. For the second query, I would probably just select fthe `CASE` expression first and then aggregate the result. Thus you wouldn't have to write the same `CASE` expression twice. This, again, can be done with a `WITH` clause.